# Why do i get a timeout when using Azure logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm using the latest preview version of Azure logic apps and one of my topics checks if a string in the header of the message matches `SOME_STRING` as seen in the code below

```
    "authenticatedresponse": {
        "conditions": [
            { 
                "expression": "@equals(coalesce(trigger().outputs?.headers?['CHECK_THIS_STRING'], ''),  'SOME_STRING')"
            }
        ],
        "inputs": {
            "statusCode": 202
        },
        "type": "Response"
    }
```

The topic is supposed to check if the condition is true and then pass on the message to a service bus. It works in 99% of the cases but sometimes I get a timeout exception message `{"code":"ActionResponseTimedOut","message":"The execution of template action 'authenticatedresponse' is failed: the client application timed out waiting for a response from service. This means that workflow took longer to respond than the alloted timeout value. The connection maintained between the client application and service will be closed and client application will get an HTTP status code 504 Gateway Timeout."}`

As you can see it's a really simple condition so it really shouldn't take a lot of time to execute. Does anyone have an idea about what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple causes for this. The common ones are:

1. Actions prior to the Response action take more than 90 seconds to complete
2. Logic App is being throttled due to exceeding the limit of number of actions that the app may complete in a 5 minute period (e.g. large number of simultaneous runs of your app such as under high load)

For (1), reduce complexity of your application, move time-sensitive actions after the Response step, or split the application into multiple pieces.

For (2), the [current default limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#throughput-limits) is 100k actions that may be completed within a given 5 minute period, after which your application will be throttled. You can verify this is occurring by visiting the Metrics section of the Azure Portal, selecting your application, then add the "Action Throttled Events" (or "Trigger Throttled Events"). If that is the issue, you can configure your application for ["High Throughput Mode"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#run-high-throughput-mode) (currently in preview) to increase the limit to 300k. Microsoft's instructions didn't work for me to enable via ARM template, but this code did:

```
  "properties": {
    "state": "Enabled",
    "runtimeConfiguration": {
      "operationOptions": "OptimizedForHighThroughput"
    },...
```

Answer (score 0):

The response action timeout is based on overall execution duration of the logic app run, not just execution duration of the response action itself.

So if the logic app run is taking more than 90 seconds to complete (reach the Response action), the client connection is closed (assuming the client still awaits the http response) and the Response action is failed.

Comment: Okay, but it is still weird that I get a timeout right? I'm not replying to the message but simply pass it on to an Azure service bus. What can I be doing that causes it to take 90 s to complete?